# Mat-checkbox causing "Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'active'" in reactive form

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I've looked through dozens of examples, and they all look nearly identical to what I've done, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm using reactive forms and here is some cut-down code to show what I'm doing

```
<form [formGroup]="companyEditForm" (ngsubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <mat-form-field class=field>
        <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
        <input matinput matNativeControl type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="required" />
        <mat-error *ngIf="(companyEditForm.get('name').touched || companyEditForm.get('name').dirty) && companyEditForm.get('name').invalid" class="alert">
            *Name is required
        </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <div>
        <mat-checkbox class="checkbox" formControlName="active" name="active" >Active</mat-checkbox>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="button" mat-raised-button (click)="onSubmit()" [disabled]="companyEditForm.invalid || companyEditForm.pristine">Save</button>
</form>
```

The component would look like this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormArray, FormGroup, Validators, AbstractControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-company-edit',
  templateUrl: './company-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./company-edit.component.scss'],
})
export class CompanyEditComponent {

    key: string;
    companyEditForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 
    this.companyEditForm = this.createFormGroup()
  }

  onSubmit() {
    //submits form data
  }

  createFormGroup() {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      name: '',
      active: true
    })
  }
}
```

My only hint is that in the debug console, I see this error:

`Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'active'`

On the actual page, I can see the "Active" label, but there is no checkbox next to it. I did realize that I didn't have the MatCheckboxModule imported, so I fixed that, but there has been no change in the error I'm getting. As far as I can tell, my mat-checkbox here is nearly identical to other examples I've looked at, so I'm stumped as to what is wrong.

Comment: did you define companyEditForm?

Comment: Hi Herman, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please provide a [mcve] of your current code? Your current code doesn't mention how the `createFormGroup` method is called, nor is there any information on how the `companyEditForm` value is defined/set as Logan mentioned.

Comment: Ah sorry about that, I've updated the question to show more of what I'm doing
@LoganYoung companyEditForm is defined, I have other fields that are working as intended, only the mat-checkbox fields are having issues. using a standard input element with type="checkbox" was working as well

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48000569/8774905, it might help